# Не вставляется перевод строки

Tags: java

Из одного текстового файла во второй надо переписать все строки, вставив в конец каждой строчки ее длину. Вот листинг

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\prg1\\Letter.txt", false)){ 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\prg1\\test2.txt"));

        String tmp;
        while( (tmp = reader.readLine())!= null ){
            writer.write(tmp);
            writer.write(tmp.length());
            writer.append( '\n');// делал также writer.write( '\n');
        }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в результирующем файле "Letter.txt" переходы на новую строку отсутствуют, т.е  writer.append( '\n') или  writer.write( '\n') не работает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

`writer.write(System.lineSeparator());`

или

`writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

P.S.: поскольку вы используете конструкцию [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), то использовать `writer.close();` нет необходимости. Также можно объявление `reader` перенести в `try(...)`:

```
try(
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\prg1\\Letter.txt", false);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\prg1\\test2.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr)
) {
  ... // В блоке try теперь не нужно вызывать методы close().
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле перевод строки это два символа `\r\n`. Но многие текстовые редакторы любой из них могут понимать как перевод строки. Я полагаю ты открываешь итоговый файл блокнотом, он то как раз и не понимает одиночный `\n`